# In a formula search for closest future date in list, how do I include current week?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This array formula searches from a list of dates in Column A and returns the closest future date from today:

```
=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(A2:A>TODAY(),A2:A)))
```

Column A:

```
8/4/2017
8/11/2017
8/8/2017
8/25/2017
9/1/2017
```

Today is 8/25/2017. We want it to select `8/25/2017`, not `9/1/2017`.

How do we fix the formula to include TODAY and future dates? (Not just future date because it's selecting future date on the actual date.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the cut off one day earlier:

```
  =ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(A2:A>TODAY()-1,A2:A)))
```

(I have deducted `1` from TODAY.)